# MAMP error: couldn't be started

Tags: apache, process, mamp

I've installed MAMP (windows) and I can't start it. When I first opened it, i got the usual error of port 80 already used. But after i changed it to another port, 8888, i got a diferent error:

```
Could not wait for starting of Apache child. Apache parent process id is: 6208
```

I'm always getting this error, even though i've reinstalled MAMP and tried diferent ports as well, like 2222, and I keep getting the error. Besides, the process id in the error is always diferent every time i try to start MAMP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "MAMP for Windows" IS for Windows! I do prefer it to a WAMP due to simplicity.

After getting a "Could not wait for starting of Apache child. Apache parent process id is"

1. I have **disable**d a Windows **firewall**.
2. Then, I have **uninstall**ed the **.NET, C++,** and then the **MAMP**.
3. Then, I have **install**ed the **MAMP again**, with all the .Net and C++ files that come with it.
4. Then, **enable**d the **firewall** back.

It now works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all MAMP is not for windows it stands for Mac Apache Mysql Php so you need to install WAMP(Windows Apache Mysql Php) than if you have installed Wamp, change the port to 80 again. the error(port 80 already in use) comes from one of the following problems:

- Skype: Make sure that you have stopped skype or unistall it.
- SQL Server Reporting System: if you have installed sql server so please stop the process of SQL server reporting system.

After this tips restart your server and the problem is solved. If still the problem is not solved comment back.