# Apache won't start in MAMP on PC

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I'm using MAMP on Win 8.1. It has been working fine. But today I opened it up and it threw an error "Could not wait for starting of Apache child." It was MAMP 3.0.1. I then tried uninstall and re-install it as is mentioned in
[MAMP error: couldn't be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232761/mamp-error-couldnt-be-started) . The new version is MAMP 3.0.4. But instead of throwing errors, it simply stuck at the starting window with the green bar scrolling forever...

Other posts I could find about this problem are mostly MAC versions, and I can't find any file named "envvars".

However, on both MAMP 3.0.1 and 3.0.4, if I switch the version of PHP in "Preferences->PHP->Standard Version" to anything other than 5.6.7, it worked. Is it that the windows version of MAMP still doesn't support PHP 5.6.7? But it worked fine before today...

Comment: It should work fine with PHP 5.6.7. What is the exact error you are getting when you trying running apache?

Comment: This might sound crazy but quit skype and then start mamp, sometimes they use the same ports so mamp cant start :(

Comment: @Erick in MAMP 3.0.1, it threw "Could not wait for starting of Apache child..." In MAMP 3.0.4, it stuck at starting the servers. - the two green lights on top right indicating Apache Server and MySQL Server are grey. I now reinstalled it again and it's working with the default 5.6.3.

Comment: @Arlind I'm not using Skype, and I checked the ports, no other app is using port 80... it worked fine until today...

Comment: Here's a question for you. Why are you using MAMP, which is intended for Machintosh computers, instead of WAMP if you're on Win8?

Comment: well, it works fine with PHP 5.6.3 and 5.5.19. If I copy the PHP 5.6.7 to MAMP\bin\php, then MAMP won't work. the apache_error log doesn't have anything suspicious, all sessions look the same, with "Starting thread to listen on port 80" at the end. the sessions that didn't work had green bar kept scrolling, Apache and MySQL Server lights on the top right were grey, "Open start page" were grey... my computer is running the same apps when choosing PHP5.6.7 or 5.6.3 or other version in Preference

Comment: @j08691 well I first started with it and found it very easy to use. I've been using it for a year with no problems at all until now. It worked fine on Win 7, 8 and 8.1. I guess the downside is just there isn't much resource to turn to when I finally have problems...

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the logs in \MAMP\logs ?

Also which maybe ins't your problem. I upgraded to the latest MAMP (3.2.1) yesterday on my Windows 7 Pro computer and suddenly the Apache and MySQL server would not start anymore. MAMP would execute though. After some debugging I installed the latest MS .Net Framework 4.6 and everything worked fine.

Comment: this is not an answere. Its more a question and an other solution for a problem that you experienced not what op did.